# How do I use mysqldump to export only the CREATE TABLE commands?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use `mysqldump` to export only the DB schema -- no data, no additional SQL comments, just the `CREATE TABLE` commands. Here's what I've got so far:

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p --no-data --compact  some_db
```

It almost achieves what I want, but I'd like to eliminate the "character set" lines (those like the first 3 lines in the example output below). Is there a `mysqldump` option to do that?

```
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bar_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bazz` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=369348 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `bar` (
...etc.
```

Here's my version info, in case that matters:

```
mysqldump Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.1.34, for Win32 (ia32)
mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.34, for Win32 (ia32)
```

Comment: Couldn't you more simply use the SQL query `SHOW CREATE TABL tbl_nameE` (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This uses grep as well, but it seems to work:

```
mysqldump -d --compact --compatible=mysql323 ${dbname}|egrep -v "(^SET|^/\*\!)"
```

I'm using:

> Ver 10.11 Distrib 5.0.51a, for
>   debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)

Comment: -d is --no-data so this should answer the question

Answer (score 13):

Here is the command to dump the schema without the character set and AUTO_INCREMENT.

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p --no-data  YOUR_DATABASE_HERE |egrep -v "(^SET|^/\*\!)" | sed 's/ AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]*\b//'
```

Here is the command to dump the schema without the character set, AUTO_INCREMENT and the comments

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p --no-data --compact YOUR_DATABASE_HERE |egrep -v "(^SET|^/\*\!)" | sed 's/ AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]*\b//'
```

Answer (score 7):

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE mytablename;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
mysqldump --compact --no-set-names --skip-opt --no-data DB | sed "/ SET /d"
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the --skip-comments option mentioned in the manual?  Does it help?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_comments

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It looks promising, but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `--skip-set-charset` option.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_set-charset