# Generate CREATE statements for all MySql Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, information-schema

I want All **CREATE** statements of MySql Tables in 1 query result.

For example, **INFORMATION_SCHEMA** contains all *table names,comments* etc. but where are the **CREATE** statements are stored in MySql ? can it be retrieved in one query for all tables ?

Currently i am retrieving **TABLE** ddl as below for 1 table. I have 100's of tables so i can repeat the same everytime which is time taking process

```
show create table row_format;
```

Comment: The `CREATE` statements aren't stored anywhere. `show create table` recreates them from the data in `information_schema`.

Comment: @Barmar: could you please how to do it manually than retrieving it using show command ? I will follow the same logic to extract all create statement in 1 query

Comment: I don't know any way other than doing lots of `show create table` statements. Why do you need to do this? Why can't you get the specific information you need from `information_schema`?

Comment: Is this okay for you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9461887/1940685

Comment: @Barmar : I need all Table DDLs now to run it in another schema !

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p --no-data --compact  some_db


mysqldump -d --compact --compatible=mysql323 ${dbname}|egrep -v "(^SET|^/\*\!)"
```

[How do I use mysqldump to export only the CREATE TABLE commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842076/how-do-i-use-mysqldump-to-export-only-the-create-table-commands)

Comment: I can not execute the above as query ? How do i execute it in mysql Workbench ?

Comment: it says, 
C:\Users\Toshiba>mysqldump -d --compact --compatible=mysql323 ${dbname}|egrep -v
 "(^SET|^/\*\!)"
'egrep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: These are Unix commands. You'll need to figure out the equivalent on Windows.

Comment: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/298 .. This will work in windows as well. But you need to execute it from mysql shell

Comment: cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin

Comment: This command may generate non-executable statements. In my case, it is defining a foreign key to another table that is not yet created. A smarter generated script would create the two tables first, then alter one table to reference the other.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this today, and [the `mysqldump` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18050973/2223027) generated me a .sql file that I could not import: it declared full `CREATE TABLE` statements with foreign keys pointing to tables it had not declared yet.

Instead, I used [Liquibase](https://docs.liquibase.com/):

1. Download MySQL Connector/J (pick Platform Independent): https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
2. From the directory where you downloaded the connector jar, create a `liquibase.properties` file and edit it like so:

```
outputDefaultSchema=true
includeSchema=true
driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/replace_with_your_db
username=replace with your MySQL user
password=replace with your MySQL password
classpath=full path of the MySQL connector, for instance C:\mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar
```

3. [Install Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/download) then run:

```sh
liquibase --changeLogFile=schema.mysql.sql generateChangeLog
```

This will generate SQL commands for your schema, all in the right order.

For instance:

```sql
CREATE TABLE address (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, line VARCHAR(128) NULL, owner_id BIGINT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE person (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE address ADD CONSTRAINT fk_address_person FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES person (id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

Answer (score -4):

Someone just showed me an easier way.

1. Highlight all the tables
2. Right click.
3. Select 'Copy to Clipboard' and then 'Create statements'.
4. Go to a text editor and paste and everything is there.

Comment: This is probably a feature of whatever database management software you use.  I know MSSQL Management Studio has something similar to that.  However they only listed MySQL which as far as I'm aware doesn't even have a default UI application to manage it with (maybe Workbench?) but that didn't have right-click functionality last I checked.

Comment: it worked for me in workbench. Thank you very much @Curtis!

Answer (score -4):

1. Select the Database required
2. Select the tables (**Check all** *for all tables*) you want to ***SHOW CREATE TABLE***
3. Click on dropdown **With Selected:** and select **Show create**