# Get table dependency order in jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a set of tables [A,B,C,D] in MySQL Database

The dependency is as follows
B->C->A and D->A
that is, A has a PrimaryKey , C has a foreign key which points A's Primary key and B has a Foreign key which points C's primary key and similarly D has a foreign key which points A's primary key.

I need to get the dependency sorted tables list so that I don't get problems during insertion

How do I get the table list as [A,C,B,D] through JDBC ?

Comment: Good question, +1. Some people will downvote anything. The world needs a tool for this. Shouldn't be difficult, just a topological sort on the FOREIGN KEY clauses in the [SHOW CREATE TABLE outputs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18050973/207421).

Comment: There is no API for this in JDBC. You need to write this yourself. Some SQL clients can do this for you.

Comment: @EJP I think it would be better to use the JDBC database metadata (eg `DatabaseMetaData.getImportedKeys()` or `DatabaseMetaData.getExportedKeys()` to do this, otherwise you bind your solution to MySQL instead of having a generic solution that 1) would also work on other systems and 2) requires less parsing.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Agreed, good idea. I plan to write this thing next week and post it here, if nobody beats me to it.

Comment: @EJP Sounds like an interesting project. I seem to remember that Eclipse Data Tools Project had something like that, but I haven't used that in a while, so the details escape me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just figured this out for a recent school project. There are a few ways to do it such as using ResultSetMetaData and setting up a loop with an exception listener; however the quickest way is what I have below. **read** is a *Statement* object and **results** is a *ResultSet* object. Using this you should be able to write a loop that cycles through all of the names. I think this method is better because it returns a ResultSet of just the table names. If you add the modifer FULL, a second column will appear describing what kind of tables each are such as base table. Hope this helps!

```
read.execute("SHOW TABLES IN your_database_name;");
results = read.getResultSet();
results.first();
System.out.println(results.getString(1));
```

[MySQL Show Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html)

Comment: From here you can store it in an array or a list. If you need the implementation for obtaining the number of columns and rows in a ResultSet let me know as I have that as well.

Comment: You can also use constraints for the keys and use code to interpret it all. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-constraints-table.html